# Move scrollbar to some point in c#

Tags: c#, scrollbar, move, point

EveryBody

I got a panel containing information to add user .. and it's scrollable .
there is a button called add_user onclick check the field verification and the add these user to data base .

the question is : when press the button and have an error move the scroll of panel to the field containing these error ... like on website .

could anyone give me a code ... Plz Help

Comment: Which technology are you using (platform, language, framework, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a WinForms app? Or a website?

In WinForms, if you give the field focus (by calling its Focus() method), that will automatically move the scrollbar to the area of the panel containing the field.